# Open SMS conversation list in android

Tags: android, sms

I use this code to open SMS conversation list in Android. It works very well in most of the phones:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList");
startActivity(intent);
```

But in some phones (like Galaxy S3) I get this error:

*java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.android.mms/ui.ConversationList } from ProcessRecord{-------} not exported from uid 10098*

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess i'd say you've declared ConversationList twice in your manifest file. Check your manifest file.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean? The manifest is the same for all phones.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987506/java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-starting-intent-com-android-cale). Galaxy S3 uses custom Android not "standard one". And you are not allowed to launch that activity